# How did ancient Indonesians and other South East Asians become Hindus?

Tags: vedas, history, brahmins, india

While Hinduism is a non proselytising religion and Brahmins were neither allowed to cross oceans nor to marry mlecchas ,how did Hindus convert Indonesians to Hinduism ? And how were Varnas Created in Indonesia ? There is a mention of Kaundinya marrying a Naga Kanye in Kamvuja (Cambodia) and his sona became Hindus . Why didn't Brahmins consider these Indonesians as Mlecchas?

Comment: Tamil kings (Chera,Chola,Pandya) did the invasions of SE Asia. Not sure if Brahmins crossed oceans. But kshatriyas (kings) probably didn't have such restrictions.

Comment: Why are people voting to close this question? It has to do with history of Hinduism, which is within scope

Comment: @Carmensandiego even if i tried to answer with some sources , the question i think is too wide. If you consider the amount of information needed in a historical perspective you can almost write a book on it.

Comment: @LuckyPashu - Just noticed that there is a close vote on "Need more focus".  I thought close votes were with respect to scope. So yeah, OP needs to decide which particular question is of interest to him

Comment: @Pranav i suggest you looking at this text :   DE C ASPARIS , J.G. 1992. Some Notes on Ancient Indian Ritual in Indonesia. In Ritual, State and History in South Asia. Essays in Honour of J.C. Heesterman, edited by A.W. van den Hoek, D.H.A. Kolff, and M.S. Oort (Memoirs of the Kern Institute 5), Leiden, New York, and K¨oln: Brill, pp. 480–492.

Answer (score 0):

Well , probably it followed commercial routes towards Southeast Asia among the Khmers, the Chams, and the Javanese.In the beginning , from the 3rd century foward  There was a connubium of both Saivism , probably Kapalikas (who really knows?) and buddhists monks . But for sure, the first tracks , also recently found (see here https://indianexpress.com/article/research/in-vietnams-shiva-linga-discovery-more-validation-of-a-farther-india-past-6440155/ ) are from Shiva and Shakti cults.

To get a little deeper on it, Quotig from Sanderson and Finot :

Among the ﬁrst the dominant religion was Saivism until the rise of the Theravada that accompanied the decline of Angkor, and Tantric Buddhism, even when it enjoyed short periods of prominence through exceptionally determined royal patronage, found itself bound to accommodate its rival.

In the kingdoms of the Chams, speakers of an Austronesian language who inhabitated the plains along the coast of the South China Sea in what is now the central part of Vietnam, most of the inscriptions that have survived, in Sanskrit and Old Cham, ranging in time from the fourth to the ﬁfteenth centuries, record acts of royal piety to Siva or to goddesses identiﬁed with his consort. There are also a few from the ninth and tenth centuries that record the installation of Tantric Mahayanist Lokesvaras, the construction of associated Viharas, and land-grants to these. But as in eastern India we ﬁnd in these that single donors supported both religions.

Indeed the situation is more striking here because in all but one case each of these inscriptions records a person’s practising both kinds of patronage, Buddhist and ´Saiva. Thus in the Bakul stele of 829 a Buddhist monk Sthavira Buddhanirvan a records that his father Samanta has donated two Viharas to the Buddha and two temples to ´Siva.

The Dong Duong stele of 875 records that King Jayendavarman alias Laks . mındra enshrined a Laksmındralokesvara and an associated Vihara, yet the bulk of this long inscription is devoted to the praise of the ´Siva Bhadresvara, who, we are told, is the source of this dynasty’s power and prosperity.

Comment: My question is how did Brahmanas convert Mlecchas into Vedic religion? In Bali they do pitru Karmas and everyone recites Gayatri Mantra (most sacred Mantra).

Comment: i see but i read : how did Hindus convert Indonesians to Hinduism ? According to historical witnesses the only form of Hinduism that in the very beginning came to these region was Saivism and Shaktism ,  with the Lingam and the Yoni. Also how someone can be converted to hinduism if it is not a religion ? (thanks to the Gods)

Comment: Probably the firsts where not Brahmins but people that learned the cult in India from Kapalikas and used it .